# Overriding Original image using pillow in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to edit an image using pillow. I see we have only options to save the edited image in new file.

Is there a way to override the original image while saving the edited image in pillow? just to know.

Comment: Why not? `im.save(original_file_path)`

Comment: yup, it worked :) thanks @zvadym. It is a kind of workaround isn't it?

Comment: you are welcome. I've added answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify any path for a new file. If you want to replace original file - just use original file path as a new path:

```
from PIL import Image

size = (128, 128)
original_file_path = 'folder/file.jpg'

try:
    im = Image.open(original_file_path)
    im.thumbnail(size)
    im.save(original_file_path)
except IOError:
    print("cannot create thumbnail for", original_file_path)
```